# multiple folders from multiple files

Tags: windows

How can I create multiple folders from multiple files set in one folder?

Example. I have 80 pdf files in one folder and I want to create 80 folders for each file to separate them.

Is this possible and how?

THX

Comment: what did you try? it certainly is possible

Comment: Hi. I tried to create a folder for each file that is in folder. I know to do it manualy one by one but it is very timely. I want to do it fast: select all files that I want and create a separate folder for each one.

Comment: Where the folder names are to be taken from?

Answer (score 2):

```
for %%x in ("*.pdf") do (
    md "%%~nx"
    move "%%x" "%%~nx"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%A in (myfolder\*.pdf) do (
    set tmp_FolderName=%%~nA
    set tmp_FileName=%%~A
    md "!tmp_FolderName!"
    move "!tmp_FileName!" "!tmp_FolderName!" >nul
)

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
endlocal
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Super User. Can you explain the above code? Thanks!

Comment: It's a solution similar to the one proposed by Akina.
I've included the use of **delayed expansion**, so you can use your personal variables inside the `for` cycle.
The use of personal variables allows to better manage quotes. I use this method as a standard approach in my scripts: when I have to use the content of a variable for paths in a `for`, I always remove quotes from cycle variable (`%%~A`) and always apply quotes to the assigned variables when I have to use them (`md "!tmp_FolderName!"`).